# Wilf's generatingfunctionology 1.6.6

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

So, I was reading book on generating functions(https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf), and I am not sure what was the reasoning behind setting $x=1/r$ in $(1.6.6)$, or rather is it just allowed to put any value there?

Comment: You’re much more likely to attract answers if you make your question self-contained by including any relevant context in the question instead of linking to an off-site document.

Comment: It’s a standard trick when solving partial fractions; multiply by each factor in the denominator, then plug in the corresponding root. This causes massive cancellations and makes it easy to isolate each variable